# What's the latest in the page lifecycle a module can send an HTTP header?

Tags: 7, hooks

For CDN purposes I am collecting the modified times of various pieces on the page and want to set the Last-Modified header to them. What's the latest during a request a Drupal 7 module can call `drupal_add_http_header`?

I know the answer but I think this is a very interesting question and I somehow doubt most people would know the answer, so I will leave this open for a few days and then post the answer.

#### Note

To avoid insane answers like using runkit or doing your own request cycle, I will say the answer is userland PHP only, and less than 10 line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Headers can be sent anytime up until the content is sent to the page which happens in `drupal_page_footer()`. The whole page is output buffered: `_drupal_bootstrap_page_header` has the `ob_start` and `drupal_page_footer` has the `ob_flush`.

Headers are also overwritten by default so there is no reason why you can't re-send the Last-Modified header at any point.

So, how about [`hook_exit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_exit/7) (called from `drupal_page_footer` just before the `ob_flush`).

Comment: Heh. I tried to be too clever. You are right, of course, added a little explanation on why the `print` in `drupal_deliver_html_page` doesn't start the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_page_alter()` to add an `#attached` property to the `$page` renderable array, this will be executed by `drupal_process_attached()` at the end of `drupal_render()`, which is called at the end of `drupal_render_page()`, which is called near the end of `drupal_deliver_html_page()`.

`drupal_page_footer()` is called after `drupal_render_page()`, but since the output of `drupal_render_page()` is printed, that would be too late.

Example:

```
function example_page_alter(&$page) {
  $page['#attached']['drupal_add_http_header'][] = array('Last-Modified', 'Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT');
}
```

Comment: This is the one I thought of. Small note: it needs to be `$page['#attached']['drupal_add_http_header'][]` you left out the `[]`. It's `foreach ($elements['#attached'][$callback] as $args)` { in `drupal_process_attached`.

Answer (score 0):

If the module provides the page delivery call back, then the module **should** be able to inject the header at any point up until the callback calls `drupal_get_http_header()`.

My solution was posted before the edit was added.  In terms of being possible to do it 10 LoC, how is 5?

```
function mymodule_page_delivery_callback_alter(&$delivery_callback) {
  $delivery_callback = $default_delivery_callback == 'drupal_deliver_html_page'? 'drupal_deliver_html_page' : 'mymodule_page_delivery_callback';
}

function mymodule_page_delivery_callback($page_callback_result) {
  drupal_add_http_header('X-Example', 'skwashd showing off');
  drupal_deliver_html_page($page_callback_result);
}
```

Comment: As the edit says, don't do your own request cycle. If you do this and another module comes along, do you duke it out who wins the delivery callback? And I doubt this is doable in 10 LoC anyways :)

Comment: Well, then this code is definitely not correct, a great many things will happen after this. Stay tuned! It's great to see it, however, it will help explaining things (and I will show how to do the delivery callback version correctly).